# Can't connect to Firebase Firestore Emulator

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I'm not able to connect to my local firestore emulator for hosting, storage, firestore, functions and auth.

When i connect to localhost:3000, it is blank without any data, yet i can't signup any users.

```
Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed).
```

When i connect to emulator hosting, it still pulls from the production database.

firebase.js:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_APIKEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTHDOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECTID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGEBUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_APPID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENTID,
};

//i tried configuring based on firebase docs
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
connectAuthEmulator(auth, "http://localhost:9090");
export const db = getFirestore(app);
connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080);
export const storage = getStorage(app);
connectStorageEmulator(storage, "localhost", "9199");
export const functions = getFunctions(getApp());
connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);
```

I'm using production credentials and i'm not supposed to but i don't know what to replace them with.

When i use localhost:
[image: When i use localhost]

When i use firebase emulator ip address:
[image: When i connect to host emulator]

The code for the host emulator is also pulled from the last `firebase deploy` command. When i make local changes, it only changes on localhost.

Would really appreciate any assistance.

firebase.json:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  }
}
```

Comment: try using **ip adresss** instead of **localhost**

Comment: start to emulator COLD BOOT

Comment: @Javatar, how do i do this? Please elaborate or send a link on how to do this for firebase emulator.